# Collect all non-numeric values from a column after GROUP BY clause in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, ddl

I have a MySQL Table that defines causality relation between the columns. Here `Event_B` happens because of `Event_A`. Any value present in `Event_A` is not present in `Event_B` for that `Row_ID`.

```
Row_ID   Event_A  Event_B
-------------------------
1          A1       B1 
2          A2       B3 
3          A1       B2 
4          A4       A1
```

When considering A1 from `Event_A`, its values will be all those values from `Event_B` {B1, B2}, but shall never include A1 in any case.

The values in the `Event_A` and `Event_B` columns are repetitive.

On applying `GROUP BY` clause on `Event_A`, I would like to collect all values of `Event_B` column for that respective `Event_A` into a variable/collection/set.

Need some directions on SQL Scripts to proceed ahead.

**[EDIT]:**

The solution would be like :

```
A1 -- {B1, B2}
A2 -- {B3}
A4 -- {A1}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show the desired results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you just want `group_concat()`?

```
select event_a, group_concat(event_b) as event_bs
from table t
group by event_a;
```

Comment: Or maybe `group_concat(distinct event_b order by event_b)` ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, @Gordon, I didn't notice your answer before posting mine.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Thanks a lot. Bang on !!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT Event_A, GROUP_CONCAT(Event_B) 
  FROM your_table
 GROUP BY Event_A;
```

Comment: @Tim can you please try and shed some lights on what and why you've changed it? it might help some to better grasp why you suggested the solution above

Comment: @BogdanEmilMariesan, no, I didn't change anything, when I started answering there was no any answers, but when I pressed "Add answer" button, it turned out that Gordon Linoff already answered two minutes before me. I appologized for that, as you can see under his answer.